# Personal translating tools with editable glossary

Tags: google-translate, bing-api

I know many will scream at me for making this post because it's not a proper SO question but please give me some feedback if you can before this post is closed :)

I want to implement an automatic translation script to my website.  The content of my website will be constantly changing and I want a script that will constantly translate it.  I found the Microsoft Translate and of course Google Translate API.

Basically my question is this: are there any which I can personalize?  One where I can add words which appear in my website often, add translation to them?  Or just update the glossary with terms for better translations?  In Google Translate Toolkit you have to update documents or websites and manually make changes.  I want to update the translation database and it will translate my site.  Any advice?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, this is not a proper SO questions, so this is too not a proper SO answer, but it will be enough to get you started.

The way I would go about doing what you are trying to do is to have a database with your translation for special words you have a special translation for (1 indexed column for base language, and more columns for all other languages).

Then, I would create a method that loops over all the words in a piece of text, and tries to find a translation for them in your DB, and if it doesn't find it, it will get the translation form Google / Microsoft API.

Of course this is not a perfect method of doing that, but you can develop on top of that concept to achieve something that better fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for that advice...that could possibly work.  But there is nothing like what I was asking for?  To personalize and add to the glossary of a tool that already exists?